# Error modulo between int and range?

Tags: python, int, range, typeerror

I tried to create a mini-program that counts how many primes there are until some number (the input)

```
def count_primes(num):
for i in range(num + 1):
    primes = [2]
    if i % range(2,i) != 0:
        primes.append(i)

return len(primes)
```

When I ran my program, I got an error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'int' and 'range'
```

I didn't understand how to correct my program.

Comment: what should `i % range(2,i)` be in your opinion?

Comment: It means that `i % range(2,i)` doesn't make sense. You can't divide an integer by a range to find the remainder.

Comment: I think you are using prime sieving but not the right attempt so far.

Comment: ... maybe you want `any(i%d for d in range(2,i))`? Python does not automatically "vectorize" the operation...

Answer (score 0):

the problem is with the following line

```
i % range(2,i)
```

what you are trying to do is to apply modulus between an integer and a range. which is not defined by default.

you can implement this by overloading the `__mod__(a, b)`. But, by default, you can do this between two int's or floats.

Answer (score 0):

The problem starts here

> i % range(2,i)

The variable `i` is a integer. `range(2,i)` is a list or a generator, depending on what `python` version you are using.

You cannot get the remeinder of dividing a number by a list / function.

Answer (score 0):

The error tells you that you cannot use the modulo operator with operand of types int and range, which make sense.

I think list comprehension can help you, if you don't know what it is, Wikipedia can help you with the theory (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_comprehension) and Python.org with the practical (https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

You should try this instead:

```
def count_primes(num):
    primes=[]
    for i in range(2,num+1):
        if len([i%n for n in range(1,i+1) if i%n==0])==2:
            primes.append(i)
    return len(primes)
```

This code uses a list comprehension to count the number of divisor of i and if this number is 2, it appends i to the list primes.

Comment: but, how the list will ever equal 0?  What about it?

Comment: You are right, I answer too quickly without testing sorry, I have just edited my answers which should be working well now, let me know if my explanations are unclear.